# Disable timer job

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, stsadm

Please provide me stsadm command to disable timer job in sharepoint 2007
I want to disable not delete so that in future I can enable it again if required

Answer (score 4):

Checking the list of [ststadm operations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2008/03/15/complete-reference-of-all-stsadm-operations-with-parameters-in-moss-2007-sp1.aspx) seems that there is no stsadm command for disabling a timer job. There is only a command to delete a timer job (deletessptimerjob).

In that case you are left with two options:

1. Disable the timer job using the UI in Central Administration (Central Administration -> Operations -> Job Definitions)
2. Disable the timer job programmatically

   ```
   SPJobDefinitionCollection jobDefs = webApp.JobDefinitions;
   foreach (SPJobDefinition jobDef in jobDefs)
   {
       if (jobDef.DisplayName == "YourTimerJobName")
       {
           jobDef.IsDisabled = true;
           jobDef.Update();
       }
   }
   ```